# Socket entre 2 clientes e 1 servidor em C

Tags: c, socket

**Como receber duas conexões?**

O sistema consiste em 2 clientes e um 1 servidor, o servidor deve receber as conexões e iniciar uma conversa sequencial com os clientes. Consegui implementar a comunicação entre 1 cliente e o servidor (está funcionando a comunicação sequencial via terminal), não sei como obter a segunda conexão com o 2º cliente. Pois através dessa solução eu consigo implementar a lógica do negócio onde o servidor irá receber informações processa-las e devolve-las.

**ServicorMain.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define PORTA 8585
#define BYTE 1024

main(){
        char mensagem[BYTE], *loc;
        int pontarq, tbuf, skt, tskt, escolha;
        struct sockaddr_in serv;

        system("clear");
        /**INICIALIZA ESTRUTURA SOCKETS*/
        skt = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        serv.sin_family = AF_INET;
        serv.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        serv.sin_port = htons (PORTA);
        memset(&(serv.sin_zero),0x00,sizeof(serv.sin_zero));
        tskt = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

        printf("\n    ############### Server ###############\n\n");
        /**SOCKET INICIALIZA LISTENER PARA OUVIR PORTA*/
        bind(skt,(struct sockaddr *)&serv,sizeof(struct sockaddr));
        listen(skt,1);
        printf(">> Servidor esta escutando na porta %d\n\n",PORTA);

        /**RECEBE NOVAS CONEXÕES*/
        //O problema acho que está aqui, preciso receber mais uma conexão para o sistema continuar.
        skt = accept(skt,(struct sockaddr *)&serv,&tskt);
        printf(">> A Conexao com o endereco %s foi estabelecida\n\n",inet_ntoa(serv.sin_addr));


        /**ENVIA MENSAGEM PARA CLIENTE*/
        strcpy(mensagem,"Servidor diz: olá!!!");
        send(skt,mensagem,strlen(mensagem), 0);
        sendto()
        send()
        sent
        /**RECEBE MENSAGEM DE CLIENTE*/
        tbuf = recv(skt, mensagem,BYTE, 0);
        mensagem[tbuf]=0x00;
        printf(">: %s\n",mensagem);


        /**LOOP DE COMUNICAÇÃO ENTRE CLIENTE E SERVIDOR*/
        do{
        ///recebe
        tbuf = recv(skt,mensagem,BYTE,0);
        mensagem[tbuf]=0x00;
        printf(">: Cliente diz: %s\n",mensagem);

        ///envia
        printf("> ");
        gets(mensagem);
        send(skt, mensagem, strlen(mensagem), 0);


        }while(strcmp(mensagem,"/x") != 0); ///COMUNICAÇÃO SE ENCERRA QUANDO USUARIO ENVIAR MSG= /X

        close(skt);
        printf(">> A Conexao com o host %s foi encerrada!!!\n\n",inet_ntoa(serv.sin_addr));
        exit(0);
    }
```

**ClienteMain.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>


#define SERVER_IP "127.0.0.1"
#define BYTE 1024
#define PORTA 8585
#define TITULO "\n    ############### BeM VinDo ###############\n\n"

void imprimirAguarde(void);

/************************
*          MAIN         *
************************/
main ()
{

    char mensagem[BYTE], *loc;
    int tbuf, skt, escolha;
    struct sockaddr_in serv;
    system("clear");

    /**INICIALIZA ESTRUTURA SOCKETS*/
    skt = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    serv.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(SERVER_IP);
    serv.sin_port = htons (PORTA);
    memset (&(serv.sin_zero), 0x00, sizeof (serv.sin_zero));

    /**INICIA COMUNICAÇÃO COM SERVIDOR*/
    while(connect (skt, (struct sockaddr *)&serv, sizeof (struct sockaddr)) != 0){
        imprimirAguarde();      ///AGUARDA SERVIDOR SE COMUNICAR
    }
    printf(">> A Conexao com o Servidor %s foi estabelecida na porta %d \n\n",SERVER_IP,PORTA);
    printf(">> Envie /x pra sair \n\n");


    /**RECEBE MENSAGEM DO SERVIDOR*/
    tbuf = recv (skt, mensagem, BYTE, 0);
    mensagem[tbuf] = 0x00;
    printf (">: %s\n",mensagem);

    /**ENVIA MENSAGEM PARA O SERVIDOR*/
    strcpy(mensagem, "Cliente diz: olá!!!");
    send(skt, mensagem, strlen(mensagem), 0 );


    /**LOOP DE COMUNICAÇÃO ENTRE CLIENTE E SERVIDOR*/
    do{
        ///envia
        printf("> ");
        gets(mensagem);
        send(skt, mensagem, strlen(mensagem), 0);

        ///recebe
        tbuf = recv (skt, mensagem, BYTE, 0);
        mensagem[tbuf] = 0x00;
        printf (">: Servidor diz: %s\n",mensagem);

    }while(strcmp(mensagem,"/x")!= 0);    ///COMUNICAÇÃO SE ENCERRA QUANDO USUARIO DIGITAR /X


    /**FINALIZA CONEXÃO*/
    close(skt);
    printf (">>A conexao com o servidor foi finalizada!!!\n\n");
    exit(0);
}



/**************************************************************
*   FUNÇÃO RESPOSÁVEL POR IMPRIMIR MENSAGER NA TELA           *
*   ENQUANTO AGUARDA ALGUM SERVIDOR ESTABELECER COMUNICAÇÃO   *
***************************************************************/
void imprimirAguarde(){
    int i=0;
    char dot[12] = "";
    for(i=0; i<4;i++){
        system("clear");
        printf(TITULO);
        printf("\n\nProcurando servidor.");
        printf("\nAguarde %s\n\n", dot);
        strcat(dot,".");
        sleep(1);
    }
    strcpy(dot, "");
}
```

Comment: Se estiver afim de esquentar os miolos, segue uma implementação em PHP de um servidor que atende varios clientes simultaneos **[neste link](https://github.com/flashmob/Guerrilla-SMTPd/blob/master/smtpd.php)** - Sei que a linguagem é completamente diferente, mas a lógica principal pode servir de base. O essencial da coisa: 1 loop que fica atendendo todos os clientes, e aceitando novas conexoes (mas sem bloqueio. se tiver cliente, aceita, senao continua), cada cliente tendo sua "struct" independente (feito array no caso do PHP), e cada accept válido criando uma instância dessa struct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você tem basicamente três caminhos:

1) delegar o socket de conexão recebido em accept() para um processo-filho, usando fork(). Um exemplo no qual você pode se basear é https://github.com/elvis-epx/prd-progs/blob/master/bsd_servidor.c.

2) Usar select() ou poll() para lidar com todos os sockets, inclusive o de escuta, num único processo. Um exemplo é http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Server-Example.html.

3) usar threads, **uma thread para cada conexão**, mantendo a thread principal apenas para o socket de escuta.

A opção (1) é a mais simples sob todos os aspectos: altera pouco o seu programa original e garante que uma conexão não interfere com a outra (porque cada uma corre num processo separado).

A opção (2) é a mais elegante do ponto de vista de programação POSIX, pois economiza recursos (usa apenas um processo e uma thread). Também é possível embutir tratamento de timeout na chamada a select() ou poll(). Por outro lado é a mais complexa de implementar: seu programa tem de armazenar o estado de cada conexão e reagir assincronamente aos dados recebidos, apagar o estado quando a respectiva conexão fecha, etc.

A opção (3) é normalmente desaconselhada pela complexidade adicional. Lidar com threads é sempre encrenca, só se usa quando é altamente justificado. É interessante notar que, em linguagens como Java, usar thread seria a única opção porque não se pode instanciar processos-filhos nem há programação assíncrona em Java.

Note que esta resposta visa responder à pergunta original: como atender mais de um cliente ao mesmo tempo. Existem muitas considerações de escalabilidade para o caso do seu servidor atender milhares ou dezenas de milhares de conexões simultâneas, e a resposta certa dependeria então de como seu protocolo de aplicação realmente funciona.

Comment: A opção 1. é extremamente pesada: `fork()` é uma das syscalls mais pesadas. A 2. é legal, mas não escala. Não entendo o medo geral de se usar `thread`. Elas são simples, bem entendidas e fundamentais para uma aplicação escalar nos processadores atuais. E o ideal é se usar a 2. com a 3.: várias threads, cada uma gerenciando várias conexões.

Comment: Desculpe, mas discordo da sua discordância :) Para começo de conversa, tudo que a pergunta quer é viabilizar a concorrência entre dois clientes. Considerações de escalabilidade são um problema complexo, muito além do escopo da pergunta.Sobre a opção 1 ser extremamente pesada, isso depende do protocolo de aplicação. Se o servidor for atender milhões de clientes simultâneos usando conexões que duram poucos milissegundos, talvez um fork() por cliente seja pesado, mas num caso de poucos clientes e conexões de durabilidade longa, o fork() é suficiciente, e ele é bastante rápido em qq UNIX moderno.

Comment: O fato é que mesmo servidores HTTP já foram implementados usando fork() no passado, e ainda são implementados assim para fins didáticos, e funcionam. Sobre a opção 2, ela escala e muito bem no sentido de conseguir controlar milhares de conexões de curta duração. Apenas se o processamento para tratar cada conexão for pesado é que teria de se pensar em delegar este processamento a subprocessos ou threads. Quanto a opção 3, eu quis referir-me ao uso de uma thread por conexão, que é uma forma ingênua mas muito comum. Vou esclarecer isto na minha resposta original.

Comment: Não há prova maior que o protocolo FastCGI para mostrar que o `fork` não escala. Única vantagem que vejo para o `fork`, é o fato que se uma instância sofre uma exceção, as demais continuam executando. Portanto, além de ser controlável (`kill` ftw), ela pode oferecer mais estabilidade. Mas é mais lenta, e não escala.

Comment: Estou estudando sobre o POSIX Thread (PThreads) alguem conhece, é valido o uso ou é preferivel fork? é muito facil criar threads com ele.